# Speed up loop of iteratively computing values depending on previous row and excluding rows not meeting criteria in R

Tags: r, performance, loops

I am fairly new to R and I am currently having trouble with carrying out a loop in R. As far as I am concerned, slow loops in R are due to 'poor programming'. This is most likely also the case here (although I have been trying to do my best).

I have encountered several suggestions, such as vectorization of data frames, in how to make loops more efficient. As my calculations for a given bid quote row depends on the previously validated bid quote (where the current quote, in turn, is validated based on the calculations), I could not figure out how to make vectorization possible.

My data consists of irregularly spaced in time bid- and ask-quotes. Before further data processing, I need to filter the ticks for anomalies and outliers using the 'outlier-filter', as suggested by *Dacorogna, M.M., Müller, U.A., Nagler, R.J., Olsen, R.B., Pictet, O.V. (1993). A geographical model for the daily and weekly seasonal volatility in the foreign exchange market*. (Filter is provided in their appendix). To calculate the conditions I need the 'current' bid quote and the last validated bid quote. Based on these conditions, I then (in)validate the current bid quote.

My current approach: Assuming that the first bid quote, `df[1,]`, is validated. Then iteratively compute the conditions (BConditionI, BConditionII,SConditionI,SConditionII,SConditionIII) and, hence, validation (as captured by the if statement) for a bid quote. If the 'current' bid quote is not validated, I exclude the corresponding row from the data frame. Otherwise, I  keep the data frame intact. My rationale is, or it was initially, that for `i+1` the previous row in the updated data frame would automatically be validated.

```
i <- 2
while (i<=nrow(df)){
  #for (i in seq(2,nrow(df)) ){
  #
  *#calculates the distance to previous, validated bid quote*
  df$dBidQuoteABS_V[i]<-abs(as.numeric(df$BidQuote[i]-df$BidQuote[i-1]))
  df$BConditionI[i]<-ifelse(df$dBidQuoteABS_V[i] < 0.25,1,0)
  df$dT[i]<-as.numeric(df$DateTime[i]-df$DateTime[i-1])
  df$dT[i]<-df$dT[i]/(24*60*60)
  df$BConditionII[i]<-ifelse(df$dBidQuoteABS_V[i]<2*df$spread[i-1]+0.18*df$dT[i],1,0)
  df$SConditionI[i]<-ifelse(0.0001<df$spread[i] &df$spread[i]<0.025,1,0)
  df$SConditionII[i]<-ifelse(df$dBidQuoteABS_V[i]<1.3+45*df$dT[i],1,0)
  df$SConditionIII[i]<-ifelse(df$dBidQuoteABS_V[i]<4,1,0)
  if(df$BConditionI[i]==0 |df$BConditionII[i]==0| df$SConditionI[i]==0|df$SConditionII[i]==0|df$SConditionIII[i]==0) {
    df<-df[-i, ]
  } else{
    df<-df
  }
  rownames(df) <- seq(length=nrow(df))
  i <- i+1
}
```

However, I have become skeptical about my approach. The code takes many (many) hours to execute. I also believe there is an essential error: If bid quote in row `k` (where n= total amount of rows in the `df` and k,k+1 ..k is excluded, will row `k-1` be the previously validated bid quote for bid quote at row `k`?
I tried to take this into account by replacing a previous `for (i<=nrow(df)){..` with the `while (i<=nrow(df)){...} ... i<- i+1`. I am not sure if this would help.

**What I wish to create**
Assume now that *bid quotes* on rows 1 and 2 are validated, but Bid Quote on row 3 is not valid. What I want to

```
   DateTime Bid Quote  Ask Quote dBidQuote dT     Validated
1. T1       B1         A1        -         -        YES
2. T2       B2         A2        A2-A1     T2-T1    YES
3. T3       B3         A3        A3-A2     T3-T2     NO #I therefore 'exclude this row in the loop
4. T4       B4         A4        A4-A2     T4-T2    YES  #As the previous row is not validated, the differences will be taken wrt. the validated row 3.
```